# How to connect MySQL when there are two versions in local machine and docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I have installed two versions of MySQL to my local machine(--version 5.7) and docker(--version 8.0.26). Now I want to connect the MySQL 8.0.26 which is in docker. I followed the below steps to do that,

1. Turn off 5.7 MySQL version using `sudo service mysql stop`
2. Run `sudo docker run --name=mysqlname --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --publish 3306:3306 -d mysql/mysql-server:8.0.26` command.
3. used the D create scripts.

Then I am getting an error like bellow,

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: What command/program is giving the error and how do you run that command/program?

Comment: @HansKilian When I try to connect the workbench `your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the mysql server at localhost 3306: Host '172.17.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`